# htaccess: rewritten rule doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want 'contact' to be changed into `index.php?controller=Front&action=$1&page=12` and I get a 404:

> The requested URL /symfony/LocAtMe/web/contact was not found on this server"

This is the code in my htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .tpl .inc
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php?controller=default&action=index [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?controller=Front&action=$1&page=12 [QSA, L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: just tested this and it works fine on my servers, (LINUX,APACHE) and (WINDOWS, APACHE)...could be a server setting on your end.

Comment: This `.htaccess` is in `/symfony/LocAtMe/web/`?

Comment: Yes, .htaccess is in www/symfony/LocAtMe/web/ . I've got Apache 2.4.4 on Wamp (Windows 7) and in httpd.conf: 'AllowOverride All' for the definition of the document root.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a space after the `QSA,` in the rewrite flags:

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?controller=Front&action=$1&page=12 [QSA,L]
# can't have a space here ----------------------------------------------^
```

Though that shouldn't cause the 404. You should also double check that you have mod_rewrite loaded. If it's not loaded, removing the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines should cause a 500 error.

Comment: You're right Jon, I'm getting a 500 internal server error when removing <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> and </IfModule>. But the settings in httpd.conf in Wamp (Windows 7) seem right according to what I could read: I have 'AllowOverride All' for the definition of the document root.

Comment: Also, my apologies, it's not '$1', it's 'contact'. I want 'contact' to be rewritten as 'index.php?controller=Front&action=contact&page=12'. If I type this url directly, I get the page but if I only type 'contact', I get the 404 as described earlier.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED. It is embarrassing: I couldn't find  how to load mod_rewrite until... just had to remove the # in httpd.conf before 'LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so'. See @Both3000  thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Make sure above code is placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/symfony/LocAtMe/web/.htaccess` and then use this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /symfony/LocAtMe/web/

RewriteRule ^$ index.php?controller=default&action=index [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ index.php?controller=Front&action=$1&page=12 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. I also tried: RewriteRule ^(contact)$ index.php?controller=Front&action=$1&page=12 [QSA,L], RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?controller=Front&action=contact&page=12 [QSA,L] and RewriteRule ^contact/?$ index.php?controller=Front&action=contact&page=12 [QSA,L]. Problem is, it is not rewriting anything. I think Jon is right, mod_rewrite is not loaded but I can't fix it.

Comment: if `mod_rewrite is not loaded` you will get 500 error. Also the URL that you tried is `http://site.com/symfony/LocAtMe/web/contact` right? and you placed above code in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/symfony/LocAtMe/web/.htaccess`? Also make sure .htaccess is enabled (try putting some garbage text on top and see if you get 500 error)

Comment: I tried localhost/symfony/LocAtMe/web/contact as my 'symfony' folder is wamp/www. If I type directly 'localhost/symfony/LocAtMe/web/index.php?controller=Front&action=contact&page=12', then I am getting the page I want. It is just that nothing is getting rewritten, whatever I type.    Yes I am getting a 500 if I put garbage text on top. If there is something to change in httpd.conf, I am not finding it

Comment: Do you any other runle in this .htaccess? OR any other .htaccess file?

Comment: no other .htcaccess and I only have a comment on line 1. I put the code again     #ErrorDocument 404 http://127.0.0.1/symfony/LocAtMe/web/
 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .tpl .inc
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /symfony/LocAtMe/web/
 RewriteRule ^$ index.php?controller=default&action=index [QSA]
 RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?controller=Front&action=contact&page=12 [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>

Comment: Any other .htaccess in `symfony` or `symfony/LocAtMe` ?

Comment: This is the only .htcaccess in 'symfony'

Comment: Can you change last rule to: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?controller=Front&action=$1&page=12 [QSA,L,R]` and then try visiting: `http://site.com/symfony/LocAtMe/web/abcd123` to see what you get.

Comment: 404: The requested URL /symfony/LocAtMe/web/abcd123 was not found on this server.